# How do I get the function name inside a function in PHP?

Tags: php, function

Is it possible?

```
function test()
{
  echo "function name is test";
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when is there a need for this? Is it possible to create functions that you don't know the name of?

Comment: One possible use would be logging your execution. If you're writing "I had an error in " . __FUNCTION__ to a logfile or something. This way, if the function name is changed you don't have to worry about the person remembering to change the log message.

Comment: This is also useful for calling a recursive function.

Comment: Also useful if you want to use the function name inside the function (for another use). Like to construct links based on the function, etc. (eg: `function name1()` then use **name1** again inside), would save lots of time if you have the same template for lots of functions.

Comment: this is also useful for URL

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: it is useful if you create functions manually and do not want to edit error message for every function. Adding it into error message means you have less work.

Comment: Useful if you have a lot of similar (but not identical) functions but need logging customized to each, e.g.:

`error_log('myquery.php?foo:' . pg_last_error()`

 you can do something like: 

`error_log(__FILE__ . '?' . __FUNCTION__ . ':' . pg_last_error())`

Answer (score 445, accepted):

The accurate way is to use the `__FUNCTION__` [predefined magic constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Example:

```php
class Test {
    function MethodA(){
        echo __FUNCTION__;
    }
}
```

Result: `MethodA`.

Comment: __FUNCTION__ works for non-class functions as well. Tried on PHP 7.0.8.

Answer (score 106):

You can use the [magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__METHOD__` (includes the class name) or `__FUNCTION__` (just function name) depending on if it's a method or a function... =)

Comment: __METHOD__ includes the class name, __FUNCTION__ is just that.  The latter is equally available in the method of a class.

Comment: That's true. But it's often useful to get MyClass::methodName instead of methodName.

Comment: METHOD does not necessarily return the class name; if the place of calling this is inside a trait, you'll get the trait name. If you want to get the classname of the instance used, use `get_class($this)`.

Comment: @Jonny: Traits were introduced in PHP 5.4, in 2012. So they weren't a thing when this answer was written in 2009. Please feel free to suggest an edit to update the answer for how PHP works nowadays.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using PHP 5 you can try this:

```
function a() {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    echo $trace[0]["function"];
}
```

Comment: This is incredible resource intensive. Using __FUNCTION__ or __METHOD__ is much more efficient. debug_backtrace() is great if you need more than just the function name though.

Comment: It's a bad practice to use debug_backtrace() for this purpose

Comment: THIS IS THE **ONLY CORRECT WAY** i have found !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!! because `__FUNCTION__` returns parent function name (when the current function is included in parent function)

Comment: @tazo todua.  can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

  class Test {
     function MethodA(){
         echo __FUNCTION__ ;
     }
 }
 $test = new Test;
 echo $test->MethodA();
?>
```

Result: "MethodA";

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-??code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.