# PHP: Get actual function name

Tags: php, function

I got another problem: I'm just trying to make a nice and sweet log class, and now I'd also like to log the function name in which the program is.

But, to make it better code, is there a function to get the function name of the function which is just executing? It should look just as follows:

```
<?php
function test() {
    echo "We are in my function " . getFunctionName();
}
?>
```

And the output would be

```
We are in my function test()
```

Is something possible at all?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Typing your title in Google would've given you a solution in the first hit...

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006248/how-to-get-function-name-inside-a-function-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check PHP predefined constants: [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

function test()
{
    echo "We are in my function " . __FUNCTION__;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo can try....

```
__FUNCTION__
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Use this:

```
echo __FUNCTION__;
```

Answer (score 0):

## not **`__FUNCTION__`**, but  only **`debug_backtrace()`**

works well, especially if function is included in parents!!!.... 
see: **[how to get function name inside a function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006248/how-to-get-function-name-inside-a-function-in-php)**