# How to make child method return parent name, while using method chaining

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining

I would like to know, while using method chaining in PHP, if a last chained method, can possibly return its parent.

Here is an example.

```
class foo
{
    function a(){
        return $this; 
    }

    function b()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    function c()
    {
        return $this; 
    }
}

echo (new foo)->c()->a(); // c
```

In the above example, you can see, that `a()` is to output  `'c'`. I can/have done this using arguments, or static properties, but I am thinking if it can be done another way, specially using `Reflections` which I happen to know so little about.

Comment: Natively - no. And if you need that (as well as "chaining" as a core solution) - then it's time to reconsider your logic & architecture. It's just.. bad. It's unreadable, non-scalable and unreliable

Comment: I don't think it's that bad. There are quite functions that simulate the above logic in a class context, as there should for methods.

Comment: What do you mean by `parent`?  The return of the previously called function?  Maybe explain a little better.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes. The previous function name.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have got some -1 for my helps, so I cannot comment, but I can write answer though! :)

Check this post:

[how to get function name inside a function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006248/how-to-get-function-name-inside-a-function-in-php)

and if you get your answer, yeah... help me :)

Comment: You should really read the question. It isn't related to getting function name, it;s about chaining & tracing that

Comment: WHY NOT USING http://stackoverflow.com/a/1006290/2655623 ? it contains the answer.

Comment: First - because it's awful suggestion in that answer. Second - because won't work in all cases. And third - because - why copy existing content?..